# How to read jsonp response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I have a json file (http://example.com/usr/details?jsonp=parseRespond )  on a another server that gives the response

```
{
  "id": "5572a7d648b33a462d79145d",
  "avatarHash": null,
  "bio": "",
  "bioData": null,
  "confirmed": false,
  "fullName": "Ender Widgin",
  "idPremOrgsAdmin": null,
  "initials": "EW",
  "memberType": "normal",
  "products": [],
  "status": "disconnected",
  "url": "https://example.com/enderwidgin",
  "username": "enderwidgin",
  "avatarSource": null,
  "email": null,
  "gravatarHash": null,
  "idBoards": [],
  "idOrganizations": [],
  "loginTypes": null,
  "oneTimeMessagesDismissed": null,
  "prefs": null,
  "trophies": [],
  "uploadedAvatarHash": null,
  "premiumFeatures": [],
  "idBoardsPinned": null,
  "organizations": [],
  "boards": [],
  "actions": []
}
```

How can I write this response in a div

```
function parseRespond(){ 
 // how to get the data ? 
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how you load jsonp? with ajax request?

Comment: Use JSON.parse(//your json string)

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil , I can't load the jsonp with ajax request as it's on another domain and there is No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' . So I load it like this: 
`<script src="http://example.com/usr/details?jsonp=parseRespond"></script>` and I get the response above.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Mustaghees [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wzrmL0bf/)

Comment: Here's an example on jsfiddle of *i think* what you are trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/scgough/pgpvutde/

Comment: @scgough , I managed to get response  , but it gives "Error: undefined " , what does this mean ?

Comment: It means there is a problem retreiving the JSON data back. @MahmoudGamal - I've updated my JSFiddle with your URL but it gives a 401 Unorthorized response.

Comment: @scgough , that's because the php file shows a 401 Unorthorized response error when there is callback in the  URL , I could bypass this by replacing all callback words in (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js) with Callback   , I get response but still get the same error. 
any idea ?

Comment: OK - updated: http://jsfiddle.net/scgough/pgpvutde/4/ This will stop "callback" being in the URL but your server needs to set the right MIME type for the content. I *think* it should be `application/javascript`

Comment: any luck @MahmoudGamal ?

Comment: @scgough , thank you very much. 
I think your code may work if I am the owner of the server, Actually , I can't set the MIME type for the content as the server isn't mine and I got no access to the server. I just was trying to retrieve some data from a json file but looks like it can't be done. 
Thanks , I appreciate what you have done.

Answer (score 1):

JSON.parse may be helpful,

```
function parseRespond(response){ 
    response = JSON.parse(response);
}
```

Comment: the data I get from the json file is like this : 
`{"id": "5572a7d648b33a462d79145d"}`